# Convert DateTimeOffset to Military time VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, datetime, datetimeoffset

I am needing to convert a DateTimeOffset {2/5/2014 2:28:13 PM -06:00} to Military time of 02/05/2014 14:28:13 and without the PM or the -6:00.

SOLVED:
I currently have this: row.TimeStamp is DateTimeOffset {2/5/2014 2:28:13 PM -06:00}

```
thisTime = row.TimeStamp.DateTime
currTime = Format(thisTime, "yyyy/M/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: use `thisTime.ToString` or `String.Format`, custom formats are here http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for `row.TimeStamp = {2/5/2014 2:28:13 PM -06:00}`

```
thisTime = row.TimeStamp.DateTime
currTime = Format(thisTime, "yyyy/M/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

`currTime` is then {2014/02/05 14:28:13}